# "Bad state: Too many elements" for growable array, but the whole stack is inside Flutter without any of my code

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I encounter this strange bug with the following stack trace. Notice that, the most strange thing is, **the *whole* stack is inside flutter** - thus I have completely no idea where to debug since I do not know **which** part of my code goes wrong! I would appreciate it if anyone could provide some hints on where I should debug or some approaches.

More info: It happens on *release* mode. And I really do not have more information (like a minimal reproducible sample) since it crashes on the phone of a user...

Full stacktrace:

```
StateError: Bad state: Too many elements
  File "growable_array.dart", line 261, in _GrowableList.single
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3324, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 2730, in BuildOwner.buildScope
  File "binding.dart", line 913, in WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
  File "binding.dart", line 302, in RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
  File "binding.dart", line 1117, in SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
  File "binding.dart", line 1055, in SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
  File "binding.dart", line 971, in SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
  File "zone.dart", line 1190, in _rootRun
  File "zone.dart", line 1093, in _CustomZone.run
  File "zone.dart", line 997, in _CustomZone.runGuarded
  File "hooks.dart", line 251, in _invoke
  File "hooks.dart", line 209, in _drawFrame
```

This occurs once in a while. If you need more information, here is the stack when it happens another day:

```
StateError: Bad state: Too many elements
  File "growable_array.dart", line 261, in _GrowableList.single
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 6118, in SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 6236, in MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in Element.inflateWidget
  File "framework.dart", line 3327, in Element.updateChild
  File "framework.dart", line 4652, in ComponentElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4800, in StatefulElement.performRebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4343, in Element.rebuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4606, in ComponentElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4791, in StatefulElement._firstBuild
  File "framework.dart", line 4601, in ComponentElement.mount
  File "framework.dart", line 3569, in 
...omitted
```